# Make that only the address that funded the smart contract with LINK token can call functions that will spend it

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I have a smart contract that inherits `VRFConsumerBase` in order to get random numbers. I need users to call functions that will request randomness, but in order to do that the contract must have some LINK. When someone funds the smart contract with LINK anyone can spend it afterwards by calling a function that will request randomness. How can I make that only the person that funded enough LINK to the contract can call those functions.

Comment: Have an internal accounting for your smart contract, so you know who have funded the contract and how much balance their addresses have,

Comment: But when I fund with LINK, I do it in the Link Token Smart Contract, so in order to know who transferred funds to my contract address in the Link Token Smart Contract - I would have to listen to the events or the transactions made there. I don't know if that is possible in Solidity yet.

Comment: Use transferFrom() - there are plenty of example code how to do token accounting in the smart contract. If your Solidity expertise is low, I suggest spend more time on courses and books and then tackle more complex problems.